# Android release APK fails immediately on launch on mobile device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

The Android release APK crashes on launch when I install it on mobile device. It works fine on Android Emulator. Also, debug builds work fine on Emulator.

I’ve tried the methods in the below link suggested by @bhardman, @gderaco + @sacchykhedkar and @alvelig so far with no success. 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18357

Environment:

package.json

```
…
"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.1",
"react-native": "0.58.4",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
"react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.11",
"react-navigation": "^3.2.1"
},
…
```

android/ build.gradle

```
…
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
}
…
```

App.js

```
…
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Dimensions, Button, TouchableHighlight, WebView, ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, StackActions, NavigationActions, withNavigation } from "react-navigation";

type Props = {};
export class App1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <TopMenu1 navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      <View1Map />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
…
```

Expected behaviour: 
You open the app on your mobile device. And the app opens.

Actual behaviour:
App fails to launch on Android phone. Error message: 
Unfortunately, [APP Name] had stopped.

Error messages (from logs.txt file generated from the Android phone):
I can't tell which lines are relevant. So I searched with the app name "sampleapp".

```
02-14 08:12:51.252  1062  1940 I ActivityManager: Killing 26119:com.android.defcontainer/u0a17 (adj 15): empty #17
02-14 08:12:51.260  1062  2363 I ActivityManager: Recipient 26119
02-14 08:12:51.270  1062  1385 I ActivityManager: Recipient 26671
02-14 08:12:51.295  1062  1698 D StatusBarManagerService: swetImeWindowStatus vis=0 backDisposition=0
02-14 08:12:51.341  1062  1940 D PMS     : releaseWL(23288de): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  *launch* 0x1 WorkSource{10256}
02-14 08:12:51.410  1062  1385 I ActivityManager: Process com.htc.videocenter (pid 26671) has died
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sampleapp, PID: 26718
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for ReactViewGroup
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
02-14 08:12:52.438 26718 26718 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
02-14 08:12:52.446  1062  2435 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.sampleapp/.MainActivity
02-14 08:12:52.498  1062  2435 D PMS     : acquireWL(f07ef11): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  *launch* 0x1 1062 1000 WorkSource{10256}
02-14 08:12:52.563  1062  1081 D StatusBarManagerService: setSystemUiVisibility(0x8000)
02-14 08:12:52.563  1062  1081 D StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{f67b705 u0 Application Error: com.sampleapp}
02-14 08:12:52.563  1062  1081 D StatusBarManagerService: hiding MENU key
02-14 08:12:52.832  1062  1184 D PMS     : releaseHCC(967c58c): CPU_MIN_NUM ActivityManager-MultiCore-Num 0x8000 null
02-14 08:12:52.832  1062  1184 D PMS     : releaseHCC(5a7f4d5): CPU_MIN_FREQ ActivityManager-MultiCore-Freq 0x2000 null
02-14 08:12:52.999  1062  1080 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{858d360 u0 com.sampleapp/.MainActivity t2027 f}
02-14 08:12:53.108  1062  1072 D PMS     : releaseWL(f07ef11): PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  *launch* 0x1 WorkSource{2897}
```

Comment: You really need to post a crash log. You can get one from your device by plugging your phone into your computer, open the app so it crashes, then run `adb logcat -d > logs.txt` in the terminal it will save a file called `logs.txt` to your computer. You need to look through that log to find the error that is causing your app to crash. You then need to copy that error, edit your questions, and paste in the error.

Comment: i think you forget to import TopMenu1 in App.js

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. BrijeshShiroy <TopMenu1 /> and <View1Map /> components are actually listed out further down in this same file. Sorry it wasn't clear. I only included this section to show that I have an empty {} notation.   @Andrew Thanks. I've started looking up adb. So far, I've established that adb is an Android specific thing. I will read up more on that, set up and install some stuff so I can run that command. Thanks.

Comment: @L.U. If you have android studio on your machine then you should have `adb`

Comment: @Andrew thank you. I found a way to run adb and located the logs.txt file. I can't tell which lines are relevant. So, I keyword searched for my app name "sampleapp". I don't know where to start. If you could point out which lines I should be looking at, that would narrow down my next step by a lot.

Comment: `Unable to create layer for ReactViewGroup` that’s the error. Though it is a very tricky one to debug. I think it is to do with a view that is too larger trying to be rendered.